# Hi how to count lines in python

Tags: python, string, file

i want to make script that can do something
counting every 4 lines from file for example

```
file=open('file.txt','r')

for i in file:
    'for evry 4 lines ????'
        print "hello"
```

Comment: `counting every 4 lines from file` - What do you mean by that? Do you want to print `hello` after every four lines?

Comment: Hello , :) you are going to get a lot of downvotes just for the word `"Hi"`

Comment: Is there race against other users to downvote them?

Comment: @vitali : you can accept answers that solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for idx, line in enumerate(file):
     if idx % 4 == 0:
         print "hello"`

Comment: You could make your solution more efficient by using `enumerate(file)` to avoid constructing the temporary list created by readlines.

Answer (score 0):

```
file=open('file.txt','r')
count=0
for i in file:
    if count%4==0:
        print "hello"
    count=count+1
```